# LightInject with Breeze Controller - Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, breeze, asp.net-web-api2, light-inject

I have installed LightInject.WebApi alongside Breeze.server.WebApi2 using a standard injection pattern from LightInject examples and get error stating I must "make sure the controller has a parameterless public constructor" even though when I comment out BreezeController annotation and use a standard WebApi Route (with no other changes - so the injection logic is exactly the same) the injection works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LightInject doesn't like the Breeze route being set up in PreApplicationStartMethod.

Move the MapHttpRoute from RegisterBreezePreStart() to within standard WebApiConfig.Register() method and Breeze and LightInject should work well together.